# ASP.NET MVC - NHaml issue on web.config file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, view, publishing, nhaml

I'm trying to implement NHaml views on my application, and it's all working well.
But strangely I'm getting some warnings on web.config files when publishing the application.

My nhaml parameters are:

```
<configSections>
  ...
  <section name="nhaml" type="NHaml.Configuration.NHamlConfigurationSection, NHaml"/>
</configSections>
<nhaml autoRecompile="true" templateCompiler="CSharp3" encodeHtml="false" useTabs="false" indentSize="2">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="MyApp"/>
  </assemblies>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="MyApp" />
    <add namespace="MyApp.Controllers" />
  </namespaces>
</nhaml>
```

So, it's weird because the haml views are being rendered without any problems, but every time I open the web.config file I get the following warnings:

```
Message 1   Could not find schema   information for the element   'nhaml'.            C:\inetpub\MyApp\Web.config 25  4   MyApp
Message 2   Could not find schema   information for the attribute 'autoRecompile'.    C:\inetpub\MyApp\Web.config 25  10  MyApp
Message 3   Could not find schema   information for the attribute 'templateCompiler'. C:\inetpub\MyApp\Web.config 25  31  MyApp
Message 4   Could not find schema   information for the attribute 'encodeHtml'.       C:\inetpub\MyApp\Web.config 25  58  MyApp
Message 5   Could not find schema   information for the attribute 'useTabs'.          C:\inetpub\MyApp\Web.config 25  77  MyApp
Message 6   Could not find schema   information for the attribute 'indentSize'.       C:\inetpub\MyApp\Web.config 25  93  MyApp
Message 7   Could not find schema   information for the element   'assemblies'.       C:\inetpub\MyApp\Web.config 26  6   MyApp
Message 8   Could not find schema   information for the element   'add'.              C:\inetpub\MyApp\Web.config 27  8   MyApp
Message 9   Could not find schema   information for the attribute 'assembly'.         C:\inetpub\MyApp\Web.config 27  12  MyApp
Message 10  Could not find schema   information for the element   'namespaces'.       C:\inetpub\MyApp\Web.config 29  6   MyApp
Message 11  Could not find schema   information for the element   'add'.              C:\inetpub\MyApp\Web.config 30  8   MyApp
Message 12  Could not find schema   information for the attribute 'namespace'.        C:\inetpub\MyApp\Web.config 30  12  MyApp
Message 13  Could not find schema   information for the element   'add'.              C:\inetpub\MyApp\Web.config 31  8   MyApp
Message 14  Could not find schema   information for the attribute 'namespace'.        C:\inetpub\MyApp\Web.config 31  12  MyApp
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you for your attention. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems these are just VS telling you that the custom elements cannot be found inside the XSD for what it thinks configuration files should look like. The same happens with nhibernate.

So you are not doing anything wrong and u can ignore the messages. They are just informational.

Based on this blog post 
http://fgheysels.blogspot.com/2006/04/net-20-could-not-find-schema.html

I could create an nhaml XSD for the config (the same way the nhibernate folks have) but it  is not high on my list of priorities. Feel free to have a go at it if the messages really annoy you.

Comment: That was a relief. Thanks a Lot simon, this was very helpful and informational.